# Increase /tmp directory space in linux 7 through terminal

Tags: linux

I have problem in installing oracle DB since /tmp has no required freespace. How to increase the space of /tmp folder from terminal?

Comment: A folder does not have a size limit, except by the file system it is contained in. It might be that this folder is mounted as a separate volume (partition, file system). In that case you have to increase the size of that volume. So a file system task, you will find documentation about that on google.

Comment: Hello vichi, welcome to SO. You should consider asking this question on [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com) site, as that's probably a more appropriate community and will best help with your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hope you have some free space in the disk. Its possible to make free space to a particular partition here its /tmp

Open the terminal and run

```
df -h
```

this will show the disk space currently you have in the system

to increase the space for the partition

type

```
`sudo umount /tmp`
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=1048576,mode=1777 overflow /tmp
```

this will increase the size by 1MB if you add and extra zero that is 10485760 will increase the size by 10MB. Add space upon how much you needed.